# jQuery Plug-in for Date & Time Picker

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a jQuery date & time picker Plug-in that can do the following:

- output a single date and a time from the picker tool
- output a date range and a time for each date in the range from the picker tool
- output multiple times for a single date from the picker tool
- output multiple times for a date range from the picker tool

Does anyone know of such a plug-in? I have googled and not found something like this yet.

**Specs Described:**

1. Ideally, the web page contains a datetime picker widget with calendar and timeline.
2. the calendar has available dates that can be picked and has certain dates disabled and cannot be picked (ie, "blackout dates")
3. the calendar allows for the selection of a single date or starting/ending date (for a range)
4. the timeline allows for predefined times and only allows for selection of those times.

I can handle the server-side manipulation of the output to get the selected dates & times into the DB

Comment: I have a fair list of jQuery plugins I've used; however before I think on those I have some questions: What user interaction and what format where you looking for for the bottom 3 complicated requirements? (ie have a for example 'hourly' option? or have a dedicated repeat option which has options such as daily, weekly, hourly etc? I'd suggest following the [ISO standard for repeating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Repeating_intervals) - which is a single entry in your system which you then calculate dates from. So give that a thought and let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @NickWilde. I updated my OQ with specs that might help you respond.

Comment: yes that looks great, I'll just have to think and confirm on a couple I've used to see if they are close enough (don't think I know any *exact* matches)

Comment: Thanks @NickWilde. I am sure no plugin will give an exact match. I've tried "DateTimePicker jQuery plugin select date and time" and it is too buggy, not extremely well documented, and lacks a few key features.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Bootstrap DateTime Picker](https://github.com/tarruda/bootstrap-datetimepicker) plugin and it's good, you can pick *dates*, you can pick *time* accordingly.

You can also disable *time* functionality if not required.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)</kbd>

---

Some screenshots of the UI and functionality

**Only Date**

[image]

---

**Date/Time**

[image]

[image]

---

Bad Part : Project isn't currently maintained.

Comment: How about the "blackout dates", is it possible?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul ummmm not sure.. I don't think the Script has that handler ...